# Incremental Cartensian Coordinates Betwwen Two Known Coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra

I've done a lot of searches and haven't found exactly what I'm looking for.  I'm looking for an algorithm that will provide me the cartesian coordinates (xyz) every 100ft between two known cartesian coordinates (xyz).

Any assistance would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You have two points, $\vec{p_1} = (x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $\vec{p_2} = (x_2, y_2, z_2)$.

The line between these two points is given by:
$$(x,y,z) = \hat{v}t+\vec{p_1}$$
where $\hat{v}$ is the unit vector from $\vec{p_1}$ to $\vec{p_2}$, and $t$ ranges from $0$ to $\|\vec{p_2}-\vec{p_1}\|$.

To find the points you're looking for, substitute multiples of $100$ in for $t$: $0, 100, 200,\ldots$

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!